# FirebaseAuth logout() in Flutter doesn't work

Tags: firebase, authentication, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to log out from FirebaseAuth, but even though the user is null after I logged out, it seems like the instance is somehow still cached.
When I log out and in again, the `user.metadata.lastSignInTime` and the `FirebaseAuth.instance.hashCode` are still the same as before I logged out.
That causes, that my onboarding is displayed even after the second login as I'm checking if `user.creationTime == user.lastSignInTime`.

My _logOut Method:

```
void _logOut(BuildContext context) async {
  await GoogleSignIn().signOut();
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
}
```

The initial SignUp Page whitch is beeing called when `user == null` :

```
class SignUpPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  SignUpPage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  SignUpPageState createState() => SignUpPageState();
}

class SignUpPageState extends State<SignUpPage> {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  bool isloaded = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
//detects when user logs out:
    _auth.onAuthStateChanged.listen((user) => {
          if (user == null)
            {
//This page is the first one in the route
              Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst),
              setState(() {
                isloaded = true;
              }),
            }
        });
    // Enabled persistent log-ins by checking the Firebase Auth instance for previously logged in users
    _auth.currentUser().then((user) {
      setState(() {
        isloaded = true;
      });
      if (user != null) {
        _pushPage(context, HomePage());
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
//Building Page here
}
}
```

I'm just starting with Flutter, but I tried everything I could think of to actually fully dispose the FirebaseAuth.instance in _logOut() without success.

Comment: you could try adding a popUntil or pushAndRemoveUntil inside your _logout()

Comment: @Ggriffo Thanks for the answer, but that is not my problem. My problem is, that the _auth instance is not being fully deleted from cache after logout.